# Pine Script Plotshape() not stable (the shapes are moving up and down with the change in chart)

Tags: python, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

**Normal when add the script to chart**
[image: Normal when add the script to chart]

**Goes above the bar when moving a little vertically**
[image: Goes above the bar when moving a little vertically]

```
plotshape(buy, "Buy", style=shape.labelup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, text="buy", textcolor=color.white, size = size.normal)
plotshape(sell, "Sell", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, text="sell", textcolor=color.white, size = size.normal)
```

How to solve this problem?

I removed the scale= scale.none from indicator()  version 5

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter when using my script with other scripts(it is a non V5 script), the solution is hide other scripts and then back to normal